# Seleccionar elementos de una lista basado en otra lista

Tags: python, lista, filtro

Tengo un problema con extraer elementos de una lista basado en otra lista. En particular tengo dos listas `A` y `B` y quiero extraer de `A` el valor en el cual `B` es igual a 1.

```
A = [4, 1, 1, 4]

B = [0, 1, 0, 0]

A[B==1]
Out[140]: 4
```

El comando `B==1` me da como resultado `True` porque existe ese valor en `B` y no una lista del tipo `[Flase True False False]`.

¿Como puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Saludos, este es el sitio en Español traduce tu pregunta dado que sino podria ser cerrada la misma..!!

Comment: te falto el título, tradúcelo también por favor

Comment: Entonces tu salida sería 1 ?

Answer (score 8):

### ¿Por qué no funciona?

- `B == 1` compara si el objeto `B` (`list`) es considerado igual a `1` (`int`). En Python estándar esto siempre retorna un boleano, `False` o `True`.

  Afirmas lo siguiente:

  > `B==1` me da como resultado `True` porque existe ese valor en `B`

  pero eso no es cierto realmente, en tu caso `B==1` se evalúa como `False`,  sencillamente porque `B` es una lista y `1` un entero, son objetos completamente distintos. El comportamiento que describes ("1 está en la lista") es el del operador `in` realmente:

  > ```
  > >>> B = [0, 1, 0, 0]
  > >>> B == 1
  > False
  > >>> 1 in B
  > True
  > ```
- Al hacer `A[B==1]` estás realizando **indizado simple** de la lista usando `B==1` como índice (`A[False]`). Parece extraño indizar usando un boleano cuando se supone que los índices han de ser siempre enteros. Lo que ocurre es que en esencia `True` es  equivalente a 1 y `False` lo es a 0, no hay ninguna incongruencia en ello.

  Por lo tanto en nuestro ejemplo `A[B==1]` termina siendo `A[False]`, equivalente a `A[0]` que es 4.

Esa sintaxis que intentas usar es propia de NumPy no de Python estándar. en el caso de NumPy se opera de forma **vectorizada**:

```
import numpy as np


A = np.array([4, 1, 1, 4])
B = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])
```

> ```
> >>> A[B==1]
> [1]
> ```

En este caso `B==1` no compara si el objeto `B` es igual a `1`, sino que **compara elemento por elemento del array `B` si dicho item es igual a 1** y el resultado es un array boleano de la misma longitud que B resultado de la comparación de cada item:

```
[False  True False False]
```

a continuación se usa dicho array como filtro boleano para indizar sobre `A`.

---

### ¿Cómo puede hacerse?

En Python estándar la forma más simple de realizar un filtro boleano sobre una lista es usar una lista por compresión y [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para iterar de forma paralela sobre ambas listas:

```
>>> [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 1]
[1]
```

Esto obtiene una lista con todos los elementos de `A` en los que para el mismo índice en `B` el elemento es igual a 1. Si no hay ninguno se genera una lista o vacía.

> ```
> >>> A = [4, 1, 1, 4, 8, 7]
> >>> B = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
> >>> [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 1]
> [4, 1, 8]
>
> B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> >>> [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 1]
> []
> ```

Una ventaja de usar `zip` es que no tienes que preocuparte porque eventualmente una lista sea más pequeña que la otra (y el posible `IndexError`), `zip` deja de iterar en cuanto uno de los iterables se consume.

> ```
> >>> A = [4, 1, 1, 4]
> >>> B = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]     
> >>> [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 1]
> [4, 1]
> ```

Hay más formas de hacerlo, una de ellas puede ser usar `itertools.compress`:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.compress(A, (b == 1 for b in B)))
```

pero no ofrece ninguna ventaja sobre la versión con `map`, de hecho es algo más ineficiente (entre otras cosas por la llamada a `list()`):

```
import itertools

A = [4, 1, 1, 4, 8, 7] * 1000
B = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] * 1000

%timeit [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b == 1]
%timeit list(itertools.compress(A, (b == 1 for b in B)))
```

> ```
> 277 µs ± 4.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> 326 µs ± 5.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

Si solo te interesa un elemento, bien porque sabes que solo hay uno o porque solo te interesa el primero, podrías también hacer uso de `list.index`:

```
try:
    index = B.index(1)
except ValueError:
    a = None
else:
    a = A[index]
print(a)
```